# JSON.parse but with schema and type conversion

Tags: javascript

In C# one might deserialize an object like this:

```
class Data {
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

var json = @"
{
 "Amount": 12.78
}
";
var result = JsonConvert.Parse<Data>(json);
```

result.amount will be of type decimal.

Now, if you change decimal to double:

```
class Data {
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}

var json = @"
{
 "Amount": 12.78
}
";
var result = JsonConvert.Parse<Data>(json);
```

then result.amount will be of type double.

Is it possible to achieve the same thing in javascript? Basically I'm looking for a way to declare that one field should be parsed as a javascript number and the other should be parsed as a decimaljs decimal.

Comment: you can pass a [reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#using_the_reviver_parameter) function to `JSON.parse` if that's what you mean, but you'll need to implement the logic yourself. For a successful roundtrip it should be paired with a [replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter) provided to `JSON.stringify`

Comment: As javascript has no `decimal` or `double`, this exact example would not be possible in javascript, of course. The value will always be `number`. Does this already answer your question, or do you also care for more complex types ? e.g. like structs ? Also JS is not strogly typed, but you could use Typescript, and use type guards / type assertions.